# Does a continuous function commute with $\limsup$ of bounded sequences?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ and let $(a_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence. Prove or disprove:
>   $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}f(a_n)=f(\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n)$$

I know that $\limsup_n(\alpha a_n)= \alpha (\limsup_n a_n)$. How can I relate this to functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $f(x) = 2-x$. Then $\limsup f(a_n) = 3 \ne 1 = f(\limsup a_n)$.